# LibGDX Fill a shape with a texture

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, fill

I am making a 2D racing game. I want to fill the area of the ground object with a texture. I have the shapes of the ground (a Box2D shape). If I make images of the ground with textures, it uses a lot of RAM, so I instead want to fill the shapes with copies of a small texture.

Comment: Have you ever read official box2d manual? Box2D doesn't contain any render information because it's physics engine, not game engine.

Comment: I know it. But I can get the shape from physics and make a polygon with shaperenderer but how can I fill it with a texture?

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fg6I-5byx60